# WhatsApp template name does not exist in the translation

Tags: json, facebook, postman, whatsapp

I'm using the WhatsApp API to send template messages. Currently have an approved template created for the '`es`' language (Spanish), but the API returns 404 every time I try to send it to a phone number:

[image: see error].

[image: Check the templates in the whatsapp admin]

This has gone on for weeks now and I have been unable to contact the Facebook support team.

**Error information:**

The error string is:

> (#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation

The complete error object:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 132001,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "template name (kindo_welcome) does not exist in es"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "AukZdjNY1Ahnl_NwJXLmQZx"
    }
}
```

**Request body:**

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "namespace": "kindo",
        "name": "kindo_welcome",
        "language": {
            "code": "es"
        },
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "header",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "Juan"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Something worth noting: The first template I ever created (also in Spanish) is the only one that still works. No clear explanation as of why:

[image: proof]

Comment: did you manage to solve this? have the same problem

Comment: @gtomer No, not yet unfortunately. It's very random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but the problem for me was that I was trying to send a template that was not part of the number I was using in the WhatsApp Cloud API.

Therefore, if it did not exist in that number, it did not exist in the translation. When I used the number that the template had set, it worked.

I share the documentation about the templates so you can read more about this:

[Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/message-templates/guidelines/?locale=en_EN)

Comment: I ended up re-creating that template and triple checking my number ids. Cannot tell for sure as I made those changes gradually, but I believe that was the actual problem, thank you.

Comment: I have just one number but I get the same error message.
I get that error when I try to send a template whose language is a different one from the "hello_world" template taht has been auto generated by Meta.
I am from Italy and tried to create a template with italian language, that, accordingly to Meta docs shold have, as a code, "it". If I use just "it" I get an error that parameters are not the expected number. If I use "it_IT" I get the error described here. 
I tried to create a new template with the language "en_US", the same of the "hello_world" template and it works

Answer (score 2):

[WhatsApp template name does not exist in the translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77030384/whatsapp-template-name-does-not-exist-in-the-translationi) had the same problem and what mistake i was doing all the time was
not changing the whatsapp number id and thats why is was always showing not found not found.

just make sure to change the

1. whatsapp phone number id
2. refresh the token
3. use "NAMESPACE" value its optional but helps